# Linux compiling program from source and make it portable

Tags: linux

I'm not a noob in linux but no pro user either. I have a program that I need to compile and install on 60 servers. The compiling takes alot of time and I mean A LOT!

Can I just compile it on one server and then copy the compiled code on the other servers? Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Are all the other server of the same configuration? OS version?

Comment: Yes. All of them ubuntu but some of them are x86 while others are x64. I suppose I could make 2 compiles for the 2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all servers have same OS and cpu architecture，you can do this.
But I do not recommend this.

Comment: If in addition all the servers have the same distribution release (ie all are Ubuntu 11.04), then you can do this (since this is how Linux distributions are possible; the distribution make is compiling packages!).